# Как добавить дату в заголовок столбца

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно (и можно ли вообще так) добавить столбец к таблице в БД, чтобы он содержал дату, в наименование столбца, выбранную из input с типом date ?

Делаю так:

```
query = mysqli_query($link, "ALTER TABLE name ADD COLUMN {$data['titleColumn']} DATE");
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2018-02-08 DATE' at

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо создать колонку, а потом пихать в нее дату.

Создается
`ALTER TABLE name ADD COLUMN dateColumnName DATE`

Обновляется
`UPDATE name SET dateColumnName = '{$data['date-data']}' WHERE id = 123`

Так устанавливается текущая дата
`UPDATE name SET dateColumnName = NOW() WHERE id = 123`

Comment: Я не правильно сформулировал задачу, извините.
Мне надо, чтобы дата стала наименованием колонки